# How to check condition inside hasone relation in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I'm stuck in one conditional statement checking for proper syntax to workout but didn't got so far.

```
return $this->hasOne(Activityreviewlog::className(), ['AgentActivityLogId' => 'AgentActivityLogId']);
```

I tried `OnCondition('AgentActivityId != NULL')` but it didn't work.

Here I need to check `AgentActivityId` is not null, but can't get the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AgentActivityId IS NOT NULL` instead of`AgentActivityId != NULL`.

```
return $this->hasOne(Activityreviewlog::className(), ['AgentActivityLogId' => 'AgentActivityLogId'])
    ->andOnCondition('AgentActivityId IS NOT NULL');
```

Comment: sorry i asked a wrong question , please check my question above